# Generate unit tests on Android

Tags: android, unit-testing

Colleagues,
I am having hard time to find a library/framework/etc... which could help me to generate unit tests in Android.

I know that in Java there are multiple solutions, which could generate unit tests based on the source code. Are you using anything like this for Android? 
(My project if fully written in Java).

Comment: generate unit tests? you do not generate them, you write them. and if it's in java you can writ them just like for any other java program, this is not android specific

Comment: I know that we are writing unit tests and that's fine. I know that there are some advanced technologies out there to actually generate unit tests, test code logic to detect issues etc..etc... I am looking for new ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Use just JUNIT - this should help : 
https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/local-unit-tests

Comment: thanks for getting back to me, yes I know this page. This is the classic way how to write basic tests. I would like to generate them, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Unit Test Architect](https://github.com/OrangE-3/UnitTestArchitect)

I am in the same boat as you were/are. Although TDD should be the approach for writing tests, but there may be a lot of untested code already written many times in larger projects.

One day I got frustrated with writing test cases of existing, older codebase. Hence, I thought of auto generating all the unit test cases.

I have created an **Open-source Gradle Plugin** which can be used for the above task. It is already hosted on **mavenCentral**. I have used it to generate test cases for my projects. But it can be used in any gradle project, (android, java, kotlin, kotlin+java). It may be rough around the edges but it has done it's job well for me.

BuildScript Dependency:

```
classpath "io.github.orange-3:unit-test-architect:$PLUGIN_VERSION"
```